# How do I redefine a property from a prototype?

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

How do I remove the property `p` from the object's prototype?

```
var Test = function() {};
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'p', {
  get: function () { return 5; }
});

Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, 'p', {
  get: function () { return 10; }
});
```

This produces *TypeError: Cannot redefine property: p*. Is there a way I can remove the property and re-add it? Or is it possible to set the `configurable` attribute after the property was created?

Comment: Sure, you need to define it as configurable.

Comment: The original definition isn't mine, so I can't do that. The property is defined in an external library.

Comment: Can you extend the prototype chain one level deeper (inherit from Test and put your property in the middle) or override it on the instance (that is do `function MyTest(){ t = new Test(); t.p = ...; return t; }`

Comment: No. I am trying to inject a bugfix in a library, after it's loaded and before it's execution.

Comment: Are you able to run code before that code? Or must it be after?

Comment: @Oriol: Any time. I just can't change the original code.

Comment: @stackular by design - unless you can change the original code or override `Object.defineProperty` itself this is impossible.

Comment: The point of having configurable being toggle-able and in defineProperty is to prevent what you're trying to do. It exists to prevent a property from being changed or removed.

Comment: Of course like I said you can do something like `var oldTest = Test; Test = function(){ var t = new oldTest; t.p = 10; return t;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to run code before the code you want to avoid, you can try hijacking `Object.defineProperty` to prevent adding that property:

```
var _defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
Object.defineProperty = function(obj, prop, descriptor) {
    if(obj != Test.prototype || prop != 'p')
        _defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor);
    return obj;
};
```

Or you can make it configurable, to be able to modify it later:

```
var _defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
Object.defineProperty = function(obj, prop, descriptor) {
    if(obj == Test.prototype && prop == 'p')
        descriptor.configurable = true;
    return _defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor);
};
```

At the end, you can restore the original one:

```
Object.defineProperty = _defineProperty;
```

Comment: This is a *terrible* solution, but it is the only one I've found and it seems to work fine, so I'll go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this? It would have to run before new `Test` instances are created though.

```
var Test = function () {};

Object.defineProperties(Test.prototype, {
    p: {
        get: function () {
            return 5;
        }
    },

    a: {
        get: function () {
            return 5;
        }
    }
});

Test.prototype = Object.create(Test.prototype, {
    p: {
        get: function () {
            return 10;
        }
    }
});

var t = new Test();

console.log(t.a, t.p);
```

Comment: This should work, and you could define the property as an argument of [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) rather than call `Object.defineProperty` afterwards. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/j66peg0z/

Comment: @Xotic750 Yes, I was just too lazy not to copy/paste so once again I just copy/pasted yours ;)