# Stubbing uuid with sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, uuid, sinon

So I'm updating dependencies on my project and I've run into a snag...

My unit tests were working perfectly with the below stub. However in the latest version of UUID, this seemingly has broken. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

These are simplistic extracts from the code to illustrate the method I'm using to stub the functionality of uuid and how I am using uuid in my code.

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid'

sinon.stub(uuid, 'v4').returns('some-v4-uuid')
```

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid'

const payload = {
  id: uuid.v4()
}
```

The dependency versions

- "uuid": "7.0.1"
- "sinon": "9.0.0"

[Here is the code](https://github.com/ToeFungi/event-scheduler/blob/91643ff9359c560de9c4a1271f9fb4cf14c94ad4/src/services/SchedulerService.ts#L24)

[Here is the test](https://github.com/ToeFungi/event-scheduler/blob/91643ff9359c560de9c4a1271f9fb4cf14c94ad4/test/unit/services/SchedulerService.spec.ts#L27)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the `uuid@7` dist uses `Object.defineProperty` to export the versions, I don't think [stubbing is possible](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/2041). This is annoying but you might have to put an abstraction layer on top of uuid and stub that function.

Comment: Just using `uuid@3.4.0` now. Stubbing works as expected on this version and it's stable with no vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Crediting [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218395/how-do-i-redefine-a-property-from-a-prototype):

```js
// monkey-patch Object.defineProperty to allow the method to be configurable before importing uuid:
const _defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;
let _v4;
Object.defineProperty = function(obj, prop, descriptor) {
  if (prop == 'v4') {
    descriptor.configurable = true;
    if (!_v4) { _v4 = descriptor.value; }
  }

  return _defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor);
};

import * as uuid from 'uuid';

// Initialise your desired UUIDs
const uuids = [
    'c23624e9-e21d-4f19-8853-cfca73e7109a',
    '804759ea-d5d2-4b30-b79d-98dd4bfaf053',
    '7aa53488-ad43-4467-aa3d-a97fc3bc90b8'
];

// stub it yourself
Object.defineProperty(uuid, 'v4', { value: () => uuids.shift() });

// and then if you need to restore:
Object.defineProperty(uuid, 'v4', { value: _v4 });
Object.defineProperty = _defineProperty;
```

Comment: That's a bit hacky, but as of today, the only answer I could find if your not willing/can't refactor your code so `uuid` is more easily stub-able.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new file (uuid.js) and do it like this

```
// uuid.js
const uuid = require('uuid');
    
const v4 = () => uuid.v4();
    
module.exports = { v4 };

// testcase
const uuid = require('uuid.js');//This isn't the actual npm library
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('request beta access API', () => {
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    
sandbox.mock(uuid).expects('v4')
 .returns('some-v4-uuid');
    
 //Testcases
    
});
```

Comment: This won't work because the default export was removed from uuid. It has to be imported differently now. https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#user-content-default-export-removed

Comment: @ItsGeorge This works perfectly fine in my codebase...Are you facing any issue with this approach?

Comment: @bkmalan you are likely on uuid 3.x.x or older.

Comment: @JamesWebb I'm on 8.3.2

Comment: Yeah, you can't require like `const uuid = require('uuid');` after version 3 per the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#user-content-default-export-removed - There's no default export anymore so that will produce an error.

Comment: @ItsGeorge This is the require example in npmjs page is 
`const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');` which is same as 
`const uuid = require('uuid);
 const uuidv4 = uuid.v4()`.
This is how am using in the uuid.js file.
whatever I'm exporting from uuid.js I'm again consuming it in my testcases for mocking.You can try this out.

Comment: @bkmalan, yes but the original question is about stubbing the v4 function. When you import v4 as uuidv4 like that using require, you can't stub the v4 function because there is no `v4` function to call on `uuidv4`, you just import and call `uuid4` directly in your code. Before, you would import `uuid`, call `uuid.v4` and stub `uuid.v4` in your tests. Now the new import structure makes that impossible so you have to, as the selected answer says, "put an abstraction layer on top of uuid" just to be able to stub the function in your tests.

Comment: @ItsGeorge, I agree there is no way to stub uuid v3+ directly. Like the accepted answer this is way I've implemented my abstraction layer on top of uuid. Post this implementation I'm using the abstracted layer both in my testcases and other function